# asset delivery with nginx from subfolders

Tags: nginx, lua

I have an asset server which has files stored in the following pattern:

```
t/e/s/test.jpg
```

There are always 3 directories, consisting of the first 3 letters of the filename. The client requests the image like this:

```
http://www.example.com/test.jpg
```

Is it possible - with nginx alone - to parse that request and deliver the correct file? Or do i need lua for this?

Answer (score 1):

nginx config file:

```
location / {
            alias /full/path/to/your/files/t/e/s/;
        }
```

do not forget to use last slash (`/`) in `alias` string .

to use regex parse the data use `~` sign and `$1` group var inside the config file.

Not tested but it should look like this:

```
location  ~* /([a-z]{1})([a-z]{1})([a-z]{1})(.*) {

            alias /full/path/to/your/files/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4;
        }
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. For a file `/xyzabc`, the actual path is `/x/y/z/xyzabc`

Comment: @hjpotter92 ok.